# Remove empty string after python split function

Tags: python, split

I am trying to use split function without empty string.
For instance, from a string

```
['#1(X,Y)', '#2(X,Z)', '#3(Z,Y)']
```

I want to get:

```
[ ['#1', 'X', 'Y'],['#2', 'X', 'Z'],['#3', 'Z', 'Y']]
```

I tried

```py
[ re.split('[(),]', item) for item in string ]
```

but I get

```
[ ['#1', 'X', 'Y', ''],['#2', 'X', 'Z', ''],['#3', 'Z', 'Y', '']]
```

How can I remove ''?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly but you could remove the last element of each sub-list (assuming they are always present and always at the end):

```py
[re.split('[(),]', item)[:-1] for item in string]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the empty characters inside the comprehension:

```py
[ [each for each in re.split('[(),]', item) if each != ''] for item in string ] 

Out[77]: [['#1', 'X', 'Y'], ['#2', 'X', 'Z'], ['#3', 'Z', 'Y']]
```

If you are sure empty string is always the last element, you can just discard the last element using the solution provided by @jtlz2

```py
[ re.split('[(),]', item)[:-1] for item in string ] 

Out[78]: [['#1', 'X', 'Y'], ['#2', 'X', 'Z'], ['#3', 'Z', 'Y']]
```

Comment: friendly comment: :) Did it take you 77 goes to get there? :D

Comment: Lol, Not exactly. I usually have my terminal open

Answer (score 0):

Another option is filter bool:

```py
import re

string = ['#1(X,Y)', '#2(X,Z)', '#3(Z,Y)']

print([list(filter(bool, re.split('[(),]', item))) for item in string])
```

```
[['#1', 'X', 'Y'], ['#2', 'X', 'Z'], ['#3', 'Z', 'Y']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the ) before splitting.

```
[re.split('[(,]', s.strip(')')) for s in l]
```